# Why we should use " R.id.action_settings" for TextView tag in eclipse

Tags: android

please see the following simple code. I wrote the following `XML.file` but in **MainActivity class** eclipse says me that I should use `R.id.action_settings` to use the **TextView**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     />
```

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }



}
```

Comment: Are these words accurate: "You should use R.id.action_settings to use the TextView"?

Comment: Doesn't it also tell you (most likely) that `fill_parent` is **deprecated** and you should use `match_parent`?

Comment: R.id.action_settings is for the settings entry in the menu.xml file. It has nothing to do with a TextView.

Comment: Are you showing us `/res/layout/activity_main.xml` or what?

Comment: did you check out that you've used **@+id/textView1** only for one time in entire application. you seems like beginner that's why I've mention this.

Comment: There is a small lamps in  left side the editor and when I click on the small lamp I see different options such as: **Change to action_settings** Also Why not accept the **R.id.TextView1** it is matching with **xml.file**

Comment: I understood where is the problem. When I click on the small lamp I see options. When I click on the **Create field 'textView1' in type id** then I see **R.java** in new tab and I should add the ** public static int textView1;** In the specified location to use the **R.id.textView1** But this is mockery because android studio was not such. then should I repeat for each element this way???

Comment: ... `public static int textView1;`?! you mean `private TextView textView1;`